# How to add HealthChecks for AzureKeyVault health status

Tags: .net-core, azure-keyvault, .net-6.0, health-check, akv2k8s

I was trying to add HealthChecks for AzureKeyVault to my project and added following nuget package for that :

```
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.AzureKeyVault" Version="6.0.2" />
```

And in code, added following :

```
var url = "https://123456.com";
    builder.Services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(url), keyVaultCredential,
                         options => { }, "AKV", HealthStatus.Unhealthy,
                         tags: new string[] { "azure", "keyvault", "key-vault", "azure-keyvault" });
```

But issue is, its showing `healthy` for each and every URL, just it should be proper URL.
and even in keyVaultCredential, if some random values are added, it showing status `healthy`.

Do some one know, how can use this `HealthCheck`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I found we need to add at lease one key vault secret in the opts to make it work. e.g. `options => { options.AddSecret("SQLServerConnection--connectionString");}`

Answer (score 1):

- Please check if  there are any restrictions in knowing the health
  status of azure resources or with the use of this library in your
  company VPN network .
- Try the same in different network to check if the cause is network
  issue or VPN
- Try with debugging tools to capture the traffic to verify and see response.

References:

1. [AzureKeyVault health check always returns "healthy"
   (github.com)](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/785)
2. [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/660)

Comment: Tried all the options but still the same error, it shouldn't display "healthy" when URL/credentials are not right  :(